# FIle name and class name apparently dont match or there are compile errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to drag the looking script onto my player in Unity and UUnity is not allowing me to do so because I apparently have compile errors or my class name and file name do not match. I know that there are no compile errors because nothing is highlighted in my visual studio and I have looked at the file name and the class name and the filename is "PlayerLook" and the class says:
`public class PlayerLook : MonoBehaviour`

What Visual Studio is showing:

[image]

What Unity is showing:

[image]

I have tried remaking the file and it still does not work and I have looked at youtube videos and other posts on forums which dont seem to help my case. It is also strange how whenever I create a c sharp script and try to drag it onto an object it shows the same error again sometimes even though I have only just made the file.

Any Help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Can you check the console please? I'm pretty sure there are compiler errors ... you have multiple scripts in the Inspector that haven't been compiled yet .. make sure all your files are saved and then resolve all errors in the console

Comment: "I know that there are no compile errors because nothing is highlighted in my visual studio" This could be true if Intellisense was perfect and Visual Studio was responsible for compiling the project. Neither is true. The only way to know if your code compiles properly is to allow Unity to try and compile it.